# Autocomplete tool command options

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete, bash-completion

I have an executable by the name `cmmget` in my Linux machine. It is a command line tool. I wish to develop an `auto-complete feature` for the different options of the tool.

Some example of the commands are as below:

```
$ cmmget -d healthevents
$ cmmget -d version
```

My need is to display the list of different set of options like `healthevents`, `version` etc when i type cmmget -d and the press the Tab key. Then i could select the desired option from the list and complete the command.

How easy is this to implement? Could somebody post a link where i could refer to develop this requirement?

Comment: Question is a better fit on http://superuser.com.

Comment: [This](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) is the semi-canonical refence. And no, it isn't really difficult.

Comment: I can access only www.stackoverflow.com from my company and all other sister sites of SO is blocked. This is very important for me and i had no other go than to post the question here

Comment: @Joachim, I disagree -- programming `bash` is programming `bash`...

Comment: Please dont close down my question or move to another sister site of SO. I will not be able to access the sister sites

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316) seems to be quite friendly for beginners, but I like [this article](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) more.

As for implementing it, as @Killian said, it's not difficult at all.

**Edit 2018-04-23** link above is dead, here are correct ones:

- [part 1](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1)
- [part 2](https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2)